# Помогите добавить русский в консоль

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>

void capitalizeAfterFirstOccurrence(char* строка) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t длина = strlen(строка);

    while (pos < длина) {
        // Найти начало слова
        while (pos < длина && строка[pos] == ' ') {
            pos++;
        }

        size_t wordStart = pos;

        // Найти конец слова
        while (pos < длина && строка[pos] != ' ') {
            pos++;
        }

        size_t wordEnd = pos;

        if (wordStart < wordEnd) {
            char firstChar = строка[wordStart];
            for (size_t i = wordStart + 1; i < wordEnd; ++i) {
                if (строка[i] == firstChar) {
                    строка[i] = toupper(firstChar);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    printf("Введите строку: ");


    char строка[100];
    fgets(строка, sizeof(строка), stdin);

    // Убедитесь, что строка заканчивается нулевым символом
    строка[strcspn(строка, "\n")] = '\0';

    capitalizeAfterFirstOccurrence(строка);

    printf("Результат: %s\n", строка);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В Visual C++ чтоб такое *скомпилировать*, можно использовать кодировку utf-8, и добавить ключик `/utf-8`. Но как по мне, "смешивать французский с нижегородским" — нонсенс. Это не беда наша, а преимущество, что языки программирования на чужом языке, как математика. Это же ужас — программировать что-то типа `для(целый н = 0; н != 100; ++н) { если (y < 3)  x--; иначе`...